# Positioning in CSS : How to make an absolute-positioned content display outside of its relative-positioned parent?

Tags: html, css, menu, position, containers

I'm encountering a problem that is driving me crazy, while it should appear very easy for you if you have ever been faced to it.

I'm using a drop down menu. The main menu div is relatively positioned so that it appears in the order the html is written. This menu contains absolute-positioned buttons appearing above on category clicks.
Just after the menu comes the content, in another relatively positioned div.

**The problem is that the subnav buttons are hidden by the content div.** They don't just appear behind it, it is hidden because getting outside of the menu div.

My page looks like this:

Header  (relative)

---

Menu - Category v Category v Category v

---

Content  (relative)

---

All of these have a containing parent statically-positioned for the layout appearence.

**Note :** I got it of course working by including the menu in the content div. The big challenge is that I want it outside of the content div so that the menu can be larger.

Hope I've made myself clear, thanks in advance for your replies. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Greetings, 
Duke

---------------**EDIT** ----------------

Wow. can't believe that was so easy.

The problem came from the overflow:hidden that I write quite automatically. Removing it, the content of the menu pops out of the div like magic :) Actually that's really logical, i get it now that it's working ;)

Thanks everyone and Henry for resolving it so fast.
Cheers !

Comment: Does the menu have `overflow: hidden` set? It'd be helpful if you post code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your site, you do have `overflow: hidden;` set on the menu @ `global.css` line 225.

Get rid of this, and your menu should show up.

**EDIT**

I guess a brief explanation is in order. The `overflow: hidden;` setting basically truncates any overflow. That is to say, if a container is set to `overflow: hidden;`, any overflowing content (in this case your out-of-bounds menu) is clipped.

Documentation on [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow).

Comment: Thanks again, you spotted the problem from a far ... 
I'm aware the overflow working, this is perfectly troubleshooting my day :D

Comment: Tell me Henry ... did it always work well with you ? As my content is now perfectly positionned, I realise i can't select text neither click button. As if a transparent div was over it all ...

If it isn't because of that I'll write a new topic more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

It would be really helpful if you posted the code, but you can try this: add `z-index:9999` to the submenu items and see if it works.

Comment: Hello,  
as the two div aren't in a positionning wrapper, the z-index can't be useful. I tried it tough but nothing changed. 
I post the simplified code asap.